# Add file while inserting post

Tags: wp-insert-post

Is it possible while adding post through [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) also upload images to this post from url.

Comment: yes via, `wp_insert_attachment`

Comment: @Wyck but file isn't uploaded - it just sets given url.

Comment: You need to show code on WPSE if you want a real answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach images to a post from URI via the [`media_sideload_image`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image) function:

```
$post = array(); // your post data
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );
$url = "http://s.wordpress.org/style/images/wp3-logo.png";
$desc = "The WordPress Logo";
$image = media_sideload_image( $url, $post_id, $desc );
```